# Are two instances of return in Python problematic?

Tags: python, function, duplicates, return, return-value

### Background:

An [exercise on Codeacademy](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-c7VZg/1/6) calls for creating code where a `cube` function `return`s the variable `cubed`.

Then, when that function is called by the function `by_three`, the authors suggest using another `return`:

> Make sure both functions return their values rather than printing them, and that both branches of the `if/else` statement in `by_three` have `return` statements in them.

The code, which is accepted as a correct answer, is:

```
def cube(n):
    cubed = n**3
    return cubed

def by_three(n):
    if n % 3 == 0:
        return cube(n)
    else:
        return False
```

### Question:

Why do there need to be two instances of `return`? First in `cube`, and then again in `if` for `by_three`. Shouldn't the former be enough?

Or does the duplication help the code execute, and why? Can it be harmful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function does not return anything, it defaults to returning `None`.

Your `cube` function, instead of printing the result, returns the result so it can be used elsewhere. If it were just `print cubed` instead of return, then `return cube(n)` would be equivalent to `return None`, and this isn't what you want. Because `return` *returns* (or in this case, assigns) the value to a variable.

In your `by_three` function, it is useful to have the `else: return False`, because, as mentioned above, it will otherwise return `None`. This might not be helpful, because you may need the value `False` to determine something else later in your code. The reason you were asked to put the `return`s in the if/else was because that was what Codecademy wanted you to do :p. It's probably not going to be useful for you later during Codecademy, but it's good practice :) later on when you start writing your own code :).

```
mycubed = by_three(6)
# mycubed is now 216
mycubed2 = by_three(4)
# mycubed2 is now False.
```

Always return a value from a function when there is an `if/elif/else` statement. But it's always, always handy to return something, no matter the situation. (note how **something** is the opposite of **no(ne)thing**)

Answer (score 1):

> Why do there need to be two instances of return?

There don't have to be - you can express the function in a many ways with just a single `return` statement.

There's the "only return at the end" pattern...

```
def by_three(n):
    if n % 3 == 0:
        result = cube(n)
    else:
        result = False
    return result
```

...which can be combined with the "default result" pattern...

```
def by_three(n):
    result = False
    if n % 3 == 0:
        result = cube(n)
    return result
```

...and the "do everything on one line" pattern...

```
def by_three(n):
    return False if n % 3 else cube(n)
```

...which is fairly readable, but the following is not...

```
def by_three(n):
    return next(iter(map({True: lambda x: False, False: cube}[bool(n % 3)], (n,))))
```

...although it still passes the tests on Codecademy.

---

**Update**

> ...I meant that I don't understand the need for the second instance of
>   `return` (when it's already in the first)

Well, they're two separate functions, so each needs its own `return` statement if it needs to return a value.

Comment: @Baumr Well, they're two separate functions, so each needs its own `return` statement if it needs to return a value. How else were you expecting to be able to do it?